# Scrapy, Import other file problem in Pycharm

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my scrapy project folder I captured in my pycharm
[image]

items.py

```
import scrapy
class MyscraperItem(scrapy.Item):
  title = scrapy.Field()
  writer = scrapy.Field()
  preview = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'myscraper'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['myscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'myscraper.spiders'
```

mybot.py
[image]

There is error for "from myscraper.items import MyscraperItem" however, it works when it(mybot.py) run.

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top directory is also called `myscraper`, PyCharm starts there.

If you use `from myscraper.myscraper.items import MyscraperItem` it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is correct. But, If you want to avoid typing long path everytime, you can also use `from ..items import MyscraperItem` which will also work.

`..` represents the parent directory.

Comment: I see. It is also useful for me. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know you found it useful.